# Phalcon install error on Centos : make: *** [phalcon.lo] Error 1

Tags: php, linux, gcc, centos, phalcon

I install all dependencies / requires for phalcon , and pull from git then when i run ./install i got theese errors :

```
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
/bin/sh /root/down/cphalcon/build/64bits/libtool --mode=compile gcc  -I. -I/root/down/cphalcon/build/64bits -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/down/cphalcon/build/64bits/include -I/root/down/cphalcon/build/64bits/main -I/root/down/cphalcon/build/64bits -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DPHALCON_RELEASE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -march=native -mtune=native -O2 -finline-functions -fomit-frame-pointer -fvisibility=hidden   -c /root/down/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c -o phalcon.lo
libtool: compile:  gcc -I. -I/root/down/cphalcon/build/64bits -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/down/cphalcon/build/64bits/include -I/root/down/cphalcon/build/64bits/main -I/root/down/cphalcon/build/64bits -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DPHALCON_RELEASE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -march=native -mtune=native -O2 -finline-functions -fomit-frame-pointer -fvisibility=hidden -c /root/down/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/phalcon.o
/root/down/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c: In function ‘phalcon_array_unshift’:
/root/down/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c:6058: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
make: *** [phalcon.lo] Error 1
```

What can i do ?

Comment: Use and editor (like `emacs`) to correct the line 6058 of source file `phalcon.c`, then submit a patch to upstream.

Comment: what i will do in 6058 ?

Comment: Are you running PHP 5.6? It is not supported yet by Phalcon.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your PHP is 5+ then check if you have the latest version of these packages: `php-devel` `php-mysqlnd` `gcc` `libtool`.

If still no luck try to using PHP 5.5 and install the packages: `php55-devel` `php55-mysqlnd`.

And finally if you believe that the problem isn't with your machine configurations, checkout to branches `1.3.2` or `1.3.3` and try to install again.

Comment: all of packages have latest version. I couldnt find how i will solve this problem

Comment: @MuhammetArslan Tried in the other branches?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you got this figured out by now, but I just ran into the same issue. I'm using Ubuntu through VirtualBox.

The issue was that GCC ran out of memory, so I changed the allocated memory from 512MB to 1024MB, then I ran it again successfully.